# Garamond and math fonts

Tags: fonts, pdftex, garamond

As far as I have seen, there is no definitive answer as to the best practices for using a math font together with Garamond. Currently, I have the following result:
[image]

My setup is `\usepackage{mathptmx}` with a subsequent `\usepackage{CormorantGaramond}`.
While I am happy with how the main text looks, I have a feeling there is something off
with the way math text is typeset. May I ask those more experienced in fonts, whether the text above looks ideal, from the fonts usage perspective?

Perhaps irrelevant: I am using [CMake](https://dtai.cs.kuleuven.be/static/krr/experiments/lazygrounding/jair/idp-3.2.1-lazy/docs/code/UseLATEX-cmake-macro.pdf). I would avoid, if possible, using `xelatex`.

Comment: Do you know the `ebgaramond` font has a corresponding math font with the `ebgaramond-maths` package, and even an open type math font with `garamond-math`?

Comment: `ebgaramond` is the one of the best suggestion, also `mathastext` package helps too....

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You have several options here.

### In the Modern Toolchain

Although you tagged your question with `pdftex`, my advice is to use LuaLaTeX and `unicode-math` when you can, and legacy 8-bit fonts when you have to.  You can use the OpenType Garamond Math font with

```
\usepackage{unicode-math}
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\setmathfont{Garamond-Math.otf}[StylisticSet={8,9}]
% If you want a script-style \mathscr in addition to
% the calligraphic-style \mathcal, add:
\setmathfont{Garamond-Math.otf}[range={scr,bfscr}]
```

You can check [the documentation of Garamond Math](http://mirrors.ctan.org/fonts/garamond-math/Garamond-Math.pdf) for more information about the stylistic sets available.  For example, stylistic set 9 fixes the tildes in math mode.

A simpler way to load `unicode-math` with EB Garamond and Garamond Math is:

```
\usepackage[ebgaramond]{fontsetup}
```

### With `ebgaramond-maths`

According to the documentation, the correct usage is:

```
\usepackage[cmintegrals,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\usepackage{ebgaramond-maths}
```

### With `newtx`

Based on the example preamble in section 18.4 of the `newtx` manual:

```
\usepackage[lining,semibold,scaled=1.05]{ebgaramond}% Latex BOLD renders with ebgaramond semibold
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc} % best for Western European languages
\usepackage[varqu,varl]{inconsolata}% a typewriter font must be defined
\usepackage{amsmath,amsthm}% must be loaded before newtxmath
\usepackage[ebgaramond,vvarbb,subscriptcorrection]{newtxmath} % STIX Bbb
\usepackage{bm}% load after all math to give access to bold math
```

There is also a `garamondx` option if you have installed that package.

On modern installations, you should no longer need `\usepackage{textcomp}` or `\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}`, but on older ones you might.  If you consider it necessary to define a typewriter font, you probably also want to pick a sans-serif one.

### With `mathdesign`

You can download the “expert” URW Garamond Type-1 fonts with the [`getnonfreefonts` script from TUG](http://tug.org/fonts/getnonfreefonts/) and write

```
\usepackage[garamond]{mathdesign}
\usepackage{garamondx}
```

However, URW Garamond has a restrictive license.  Loading Cormorant Garamond or EB Garamond instead should also work.  If `mathdesign` breaks small caps, the easiest fix is to load `fontaxes`.

### With Another Math Package in XeTeX

In XeTeX (and only XeTeX), you can use the EB Garamond OpenType font with a legacy math package by loading `mathspec` after the other package:

```
\usepackage{mathspec}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}
\setmathsfont(Digits,Latin,Greek)[Uppercase=Italic, Lowercase=Italic]{EB Garamond}
```

In my tests, this doesn’t always give correct spacing when you mix letters with some math symbols.

### With Another Math Package

There are at least three different Garamond legacy math alphabets.  The math design one is especially handy because it includes both Latin and Greek in upright, as well as italic, shape.  It is therefore the only legacy version of Garamond that comes with upright lowercase Greek letters, such as `\mathrm{\pi}`.

The family name of this math alphabet is `mdugm`, and `isomath` has an interface to load it for `\mathrm`, `\mathit`, `\mathbf` and `\mathbfit`.  You can attempt this with

```
\usepackage[OMLmathrm, rmdefault=mdugm]{isomath}
```

Or by redefining the math alphabets with commands such as:

```
\DeclareMathAlphabet{\mathit}{OML}{mdugm}{m}{it}
\SetMathAlphabet{\mathit}{bold}{OML}{mdugm}{mb}{it}
```

Comment: The very first option worked for me. At least for the Springer ```svjour3``` template.

Comment: Neat explanation...Helps for me too....

Answer (score 0):

Nowadays the following `usepackage` line does a very good job for having garamond both for text and math

```
\usepackage[vvarbb,ebgaramond,smallerops]{newtx}
```

The above works with the `article` class but with some other classes, like `tufte-handout` one needs to do the following or the `stix` bb-fonts do not show up.

```
\AtBeginDocument{
  \usepackage[vvarbb,ebgaramond,smallerops]{newtx}
}
```

In my opinion the upright greek letters are already distinctive, so in fact I am also using the `frenchmath` option to `newtx`