# Missing characters in Garamond-Math font

Tags: luatex, ebgaramond

I have used the first option in the accepted answer to [Garamond and math fonts](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/572826/garamond-and-math-fonts)
However, I get errors such as
`Missing character: There is no ___ (U+225C) in font [Garamond-Math.otf]:mode=bas"`
And indeed those symbols are missing in the final `pdf`.
How to fix this and make the math symbols appear? I am using `texlive-full-2019` and `lualatex`.
(For your reference, the above symbol is `\triangleeq`.)

EDIT: There are some 20-ish missing symbols, so defining them one by one is not an ideal solution. Is there anything scalable?

Comment: No, no automatic replacement.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can take the symbols that your primary math font lacks from another math font, such as STIX Two Math:

```
\documentclass{article}
\tracinglostchars=2
\usepackage{unicode-math}

\defaultfontfeatures{ Scale=MatchLowercase }
\setmainfont{EB Garamond}[Scale = 1.0]
\setmathfont{Garamond Math}
\setmathfont{STIX Two Math}[range=\triangleq]

\pagestyle{empty}

\begin{document}
\[ a\triangleq b \]
\end{document}
```

[image: Garamond Math/STIX Two Math sample]

[This document](http://mirrors.ctan.org/macros/unicodetex/latex/unicode-math/unimath-symbols.pdf) contains a number of font specimens that you can check.

**Edit:** It’s been a while, but I missed the follow-up question you edited in. You can load ranges of mathematical symbols, such as `range="2200-"22FF` (for the full mathematical symbols block).

If you’re missing most of the symbols you use, you might actually want to do it the other way around, loading a different main math font for its symbols, and then loading the letters and basic ASCII from Garamond.

Answer (score 2):

You can define missing symbol. For example:

```
\def\triangleeq{\buildrel\bigtriangleup\over=}
```

Comment: This will not work with `unicode-math`, which defers its definitions until the end of the preamble. You have to wrap the redefinition in `\AtBeginDocument` for it to take effect.