Blank export using Garamond fonts
I have been trying to get some Garamond fonts to work with TeX, as they are my usual go-to. No matter what I do though, I get a blank page on export. The error log seems to indicate that it's using "nullfont," but I don't know why that would be. I have tried this with a number of different fonts, but I will narrow it down to Garamond Expert with NewTX Math for this question. I have tried using both \setmainfont{} and the directions in the LaTeX font catalogue, but I have the same result either way. Here is a minimal .tex file that displays this behavior (there's a little extra stuff in the header because I'm exporting with Emacs org-mode. Hopefully that is not the issue):
% Created 2024-09-07 Sat 17:26
% Intended LaTeX compiler: pdflatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{longtable}
\usepackage{wrapfig}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage[normalem]{ulem}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{capt-of}
\usepackage{hyperref}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage[garamondx,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\date{}
\title{Minimallat}
\hypersetup{
 pdfauthor={Vegas Harmon},
 pdftitle={Minimallat},
 pdfkeywords={},
 pdfsubject={},
 pdfcreator={Emacs 29.1 (Org mode 9.6.24)}, 
 pdflang={English}}
\usepackage{biblatex}
\addbibresource{~/is/notes/zk/references.bib}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Lorem Ipsum}
\label{sec:org978afcb}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\section*{Dolor Sit Amet}
\label{sec:org3014109}
Litterae Latīnae. Τὰ γράμματα Ἡλληνικᾶ
\end{document}

And here is the error log: https://pastebin.com/5tS4ACid
Strangely enough, when using these settings:
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{ebgaramond}

And only those settings, for only EB Garamond, everything works. This is alright, and perfectly serviceable for now, but a) this is not what the LaTeX Font Catalogue instructions say to do for this font (I found it randomly on another TeX Exchange post), and b) I would like to use other fonts. Of course, if the official instructions don't work (and they don't for me; they just produce the same blank export), then I don't have any reliable way of using new fonts, which is clearly a problem.
I am running Ubuntu 23.10 x86_64, and I have installed texlive-full.
Thanks in advance!
EDIT 1: As per @cfr, I modified my .tex file to remove all superfluous packages, and then ran xelatex minimallat. This is the .tex file:
% Created 2024-09-07 Sat 20:58
% Intended LaTeX compiler: pdflatex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage[garamondx,cmbraces]{newtxmath}
\title{Minimallat}
\begin{document}

\maketitle

\section*{Lorem Ipsum}
\label{sec:orge8ec988}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\section*{Dolor Sit Amet}
\label{sec:org9e8ef97}
Litterae Latīnae. Τὰ γράμματα Ἡλληνικᾶ
\end{document}

And I still get similar errors. Here's an updated pastebin. I don't know if it's important, but I get the same errors if I use pdflatex minimallat instead.
Also note that I was getting the same errors with fonts that are explicitly included in texlive, such as Garamond. Interestingly, after editing my .tex file, I now get different errors when using \usepackage[urw-garamond]{mathdesign}, as seen here.
Note that for my initial problem, I did manually install garamondx/newtxmath and placed it in ~/texmf/tex/latex/commonstuff/.

welcome! please remove any packages not needed to reproduce the problem from your example and post your log as text here. if you have recent latex, you can remove the inputenc line. ('recent' = 'not truly ancient'). if you are compiling with pdflatex, loading fontenc is fine, but you can't use \setmainfont. that is for loading unicode fonts on unicode engines when fontspec is loaded (and you shouldn't load fontenc in that case). garamondx is not part of texlive. did you install it? what is the first error in your log file?

the font catalogue is not incorrect about what you can do to use ebgaramond. (this is a different garamond from the one garamondx uses, I think.) ebgaramond-maths loads ebgaramond. however, you may not have ebgaramond-maths installed. it is part of texlive, but I'm guessing it probably isn't in texlive-full. (at least, I'm assuming you're saying it didn't work and this is the most likely reason.)

the font catalogue tells you when something is or isn't part of texlive e.g. https://tug.org/FontCatalogue/garamondexpertnewtxmath/ notes that garamond expert with newtx maths is not part of texlive. this is generally for licensing reasons. only packages which meet free software criteria are included in texlive. there is a script you can use to install garamondx and some other fonts, but i don't know if it is compatible with ubuntu's configuration.

please also clarify (1) which languages you need to typeset and the extent of coverage you need for maths. for maths especially, see e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/572838/. it does, however, seem a bit odd you are getting the nullfont. usually, latex will fall back to something and you only see this inside e.g. tikzpictures.

Thank you for your comments. I did manually install all required packages that I was aware of. Details and new error logs in edit.

please post the log here. questions are meant to be self-contained so they don't bit-rot. (and pastebin is an extremely annoying pastebin site these days.) there is a lot to sort out here. it makes a big difference whether you are using xelatex or pdflatex to compile. installing font packages into your personal texmf tree is not a good idea and throwing everything into tex/latex/garamondx won't work. so it makes a big difference whether we're talking about garamondx or ebgaramond, for example. (which is probably why ebgaramond works.)

Haha, sorry. I thought it was better to not overburden the comments, and provide people with full information regarding what had been tried already up front. I had also heard that you should put things in the commonstuff directory. What should I do instead? If you could point me to a source of best practices regarding installing new packages, that would help a lot. Regardless, both xelatex and pdflatex produced the same errors.

generally, only the first error matters, but you haven't said what that is. putting packages generally into ~/texmf/tex/latex/ is fine. it is only font packages which cause issues. for garamondx, try using the getnonfreefonts script. as I say, I don't know what ubuntu does with texlive, so it might not be compatible, but, if it does work, that's easiest. (hopefully it should work.) the problem is that the files for fonts must end up in suitable directories e.g. .tfm have to go in <tree>/fonts/tfm/<vendor>/<package>/ and similarly for other files. you must also update the map ...

... files. however, it is a very bad idea to do this for your personal texmf tree because you will render all future updates to texlive useless. see https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/255711/ for an explanation. the getnonfreefonts script used to do this, but the -sys version did not. but, if you are using xelatex, you shouldn't be using fonts this way anyhow. in that case, you should use fontspec and unicode fonts.

fonts are rather complicated in the tex world ;).

This is very useful. Using that script seems to have fixed my problem... at least for garamondx. Regular included Garamond still seems to not work, but that is a separate issue so I will make a separate question. If you could point me in the direction of some resources on how pdflatex/xelatex handle fonts differently, and why exactly I should be using fontspec if I go with the latter, that would be very helpful. My main concern is that I get all the proper formatting and special characters I need with a nice looking font.

it isn't so much fontspec. it is more that you should (generally) use unicode fonts with unicode engines i.e. luatex or xetex. (preferably luatex which is better maintained.) fontspec makes that (relatively) straightforward as it provides a latex interface for specifying the fonts you want. then you can use system fonts, too - not just those installed for tex. pdftex can't use unicode fonts and requires traditional font configuration, so you need a bunch of support files. generally, this means using a package such as ebgaramond(-maths if you must), garamondx, venturis or whatever.

pdflatex is significantly faster than xelatex or lualatex. some people will tell you it is 'obsolete'. if microtypographic considerations are a concern, pdflatex or lualatex are better supported by microtype. if you need non-latin scripts, lualatex or xelatex are the way to go unless you have no choice - especially if you need cjk or rtl typesetting. (something like greek or cyrillic is not so bad, but something like japanese or arabic is really not pleasant without a unicode compiler). the font catalogue gives a good sense of what's available out-of-the-box and how to use it.

texdoc fntguide if you  want details. (I'm assuming you are not asking how to install fonts from scratch for pdflatex. that is a whole world of fun.)

please avoid using external links for the logs, your question is archived here forever and doesn't really make sense if those links break

@DavidCarlisle Okay. What should I do if the logs are too long to fit into the post, though? I am a newbie and often do not know how to sift through all of them to find the relevant details.

well basically only the first error ever matters. So the log file from the start (which shows which latex release you have) to the end of the first error message will typically fit in the post limit. Any package in the example that does not affect that part of the log should not be in the example, you can remove that before posting.

It makes little sense using XeLaTeX for a document using garamondx, because the fonts used by the package are only available in Type1 format.
You can install them with getnonfreefonts, but they have no support for Greek. If you want to mix Greek and Latin alphabets, you need to provide a font substitution.
Here I use Porson. Since the distributed font file uses a hardwired scaling factor 1.08, the .fd file is avoided by providing the same information and a different scaling factor.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[LGR,T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage{garamondx}
\usepackage[garamondx,cmbraces]{newtxmath}

\providecommand{\porsonscale}{0.993}
\DeclareFontFamily{LGR}{porson}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{porson}{m}{n}{<-> s * [\porsonscale] gporsonrg6a}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{porson}{m}{it}{<-> s * [\porsonscale] gporsonrg6a}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{porson}{b}{n}{<-> s * [\porsonscale] gporsonrg6a}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{porson}{b}{it}{<-> s * [\porsonscale] gporsonrg6a}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{porson}{m}{sl}{<-> s * [\porsonscale] gporsonrg6a}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{porson}{b}{sl}{<-> s * [\porsonscale] gporsonrg6a}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{porson}{m}{sc}{<-> s * [\porsonscale] gporsonrg6a}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{porson}{bx}{n}{<-> s * [\porsonscale] gporsonrg6a}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{porson}{bx}{it}{<-> s * [\porsonscale] gporsonrg6a}{}
\DeclareFontShape{LGR}{porson}{bx}{sl}{<-> s * [\porsonscale] gporsonrg6a}{}

\DeclareFontFamilySubstitution{LGR}{\familydefault}{porson}
\DeclareRobustCommand{\greek}{\fontencoding{LGR}\selectfont}
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textgreek}{\greek}

\begin{document}

\title{Minimallat}
\author{Chiaroscuro}

\maketitle

\section*{Lorem Ipsum}
\label{sec:orge8ec988}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint 
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\section*{Dolor Sit Amet}
\label{sec:org9e8ef97}

Litterae Latīnae. \textgreek{Τὰ γράμματα Ἡλληνικᾶ}

\end{document}


If you want to use XeLaTeX, then EB Garamond seems the best choice, supplemented by garamondx for math.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\usepackage[garamondx,cmbraces]{newtxmath}

\setmainfont{EB Garamond}

\DeclareSymbolFont{operators}{OT1}{EBGaramond-TLF}{m}{n}
\SetSymbolFont{operators}{bold}{OT1}{EBGaramond-TLF}{b}{n}

\begin{document}

\title{Minimallat}
\author{Chiaroscuro}

\maketitle

\section*{Lorem Ipsum}
\label{sec:orge8ec988}

Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, 
sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna 
aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation 
ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat. 
Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit 
esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint 
occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia 
deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.

\section*{Dolor Sit Amet}
\label{sec:org9e8ef97}

Litterae Latīnae. Τὰ γράμματα Ἡλληνικᾶ

Some math: $a+\alpha-123+\sin\beta$

\end{document}



Very helpful and detailed answer. I just want to clarify that in my case, the specific thing that went wrong was not using the getnonfreefonts script. Using that solved the issue.
